# Using BroadcastReceiver to pass Intent.EXTRAS

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Main Question: Can I use a BroadcastReceiver to pass an intent with extras to an Activity?

Setup: I have a recorded date from a DatePicker fragment and I want to make sure that the Millis time is passed to another activity, but that activity is not immediately called from that Activity that contains that fragment

I tried using the following code in the activity with the datePicker Fragment:

```
Intent intent = new Intent().putExtra(EVENT_MILLIS, eventDateMillis); 
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

in the "receiving" activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstatnceState);
setContentView...
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(EVENT_MILLIS));
```

and my call to initiate the receiver:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver () {
@Override
public void onReceive(Content content, Intent intent) {
   setReceivedDate(intent.getLongExtra(EVENT_MILLIS,0));
}
}
```

Comment: Is your activity in which intent extras are required is opening after your date picker?
Note :`BroadcastManager` is an expensive resource of Android System *(Consumes  memory)*, so try to avoid it just for passing your logic through it, instead you can use some other logic for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Broadcast` is not a good pattern and it looses efficiency of your app. Try using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) instead. It's easy to use with lower issues.